# Ports, how they can be used, and what things should be configurable

Tags: port

I am creating a port manager, and I need to know what ports can even be used for. It is not supposed to handle data taken in from the port, it is for port management.

What should be configurable to the user? I understand the basic concept of ports, but I do not know what a user would want from the manager.

I am coding this in vb.net (this is NOT a programming question, it is a port question).

Things that I have control of:

- Baud Rate
- Data Bits per transmitted/received byte
- (true/false) Discard Null bytes
- Enable/disable DTR
- Handshake protocol
- Parity scheme
- Parity replacement (byte to replace bytes received with parity errors)
- Port Name
- Read Buffer Size
- Read Timeout
- Received Bytes threshold
- Enable/disable RTS
- Stop bits per transmitted/received byte
- Write buffer size
- Write timeout

I can also close/open ports.

SPECIFICALLY:

Which of these should be "high priority", i.e. the end user can see the value/setting at all times in the manager, and which should be "low priority", the user can click on the port name to view all properties? Anything with "zero priority" should be only the default value.

Which of these should I include control over, and what should the default values be for all of these?

Thanks for the help, and i am sorry because this is probably a really dumb question. If this is the wrong place to ask, where should I ask it?

Comment: I don't think it's a dumb question, but even if it is, it's a very extensive one. I want to see the answer.

Comment: Good to see I am not completely off track! I want to see the answer too lol, and I am totally in the dark.

Comment: What do you mean by ports? TCP/IP port? The "things that you have control of" suggest old-style RS-232. What is a port manager in this context?

Comment: Is it about USB?

Comment: Serial ports. If it helps, the code namespace is System.IO.Ports.SerialPort. My understanding of serial ports is that they are for transmission of data, and are not physical ports at all, though I could be entirely wrong.

Comment: A "port manager" in this context could be used to open and close the ports created with the manager, and to edit certain aspects of the opened ports. The only thing is that I do not know which aspects a user would want to edit!

Comment: Serial ports are very much physical. There are wires coming out of (older) computers forming serial ports. E.g. they were used for connecting to modems. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port. For instance DTR is a physical wire with a physical signal (a voltage) used in synchronising communications between two physical devices.

Comment: Why do you need to use RS-232 serial ports? These days USB is used instead.

Comment: I am starting to get confused here...

Comment: What are you confused about? The serial ports (not USB) in PCs all conform to  the RS-232 standard.

Comment: Okay, so the Serial Port component handles physical ports? Would an application that can manage these appeal to anyone at this point? Or would it just be uselessly obsolete?

Comment: Specifically, would anyone even bother to pay for a copy of a port manager for this type?

Comment: No, pretty much nobody would ever pay for this application. There's just not any point...there's no reason to manage serial ports on their own, they are always used with some other application. And those other applications always already include these settings.

Comment: It is obsolete. There might be applications for old equipment that uses RS-232, but I don't think it is worth it. I think you would first have to find a customer that has a particular need. Then it could make sense to make a modern .NET application.

Comment: Also, please put the word 'Serial' in the title and the question...'Port' is very generic and means many different things.

Comment: In that case I will cease development on my port manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only needed for the user to set these 5:

- Port Name (e.g. COM1)
- Baudrate  (e.g. 9600)
- Data Bits (e.g. 8)
- Stop bits (e.g. 1)
- Parity scheme (e.g. even)

The rest can be set to reasonable defaults.